# Peek/Pop preview ignores cell corner radius in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, 3dtouch, peek-pop

I have added 3D Touch Peek/Pop functionality to my collection view cells and it works great, however I've noticed that the preview frame does not respect the corner radius of the cells.

Here's my previewing function:

```
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("scholarDetailViewController") as? ScholarDetailViewController
    let cellPosition = self.scholarsCollectionView.convertPoint(location, fromView: self.view)
    let cellIndex = self.scholarsCollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(cellPosition)

    guard let previewViewController = viewController, indexPath = cellIndex, cell = self.scholarsCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
        return nil
    }

    let scholar = self.searchBarActive ? self.searchResults[indexPath.item] as! Scholar : self.currentScholars[indexPath.item]
    previewViewController.setScholar(scholar.id)
    previewViewController.delegate = self
    previewViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize.zero
    previewingContext.sourceRect = self.view.convertRect(cell.frame, fromView: self.scholarsCollectionView)

    return previewViewController
}
```

I've tried setting the corner radius of the previewingContext sourceView and playing around with masksToBounds on the cell, but nothing I've tried so far has helped.

Here's the cell setup:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 7
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, could you upload your test-project somewhere? Thanks

Answer (score 9):

As I understand you correctly you want to have something like first, instead of second:

[image: Right one] [image: Wrong one]

Problem is that you register notification on whole view. Something like this:
`registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: self.view)`, that why your touched area know nothing about cell layer.

What you should do — register every cell personally:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let previwingController = registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: cell)
    previwingControllers[cell] = previwingController
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let previwingController = previwingControllers[cell] {
      unregisterForPreviewingWithContext(previwingController)
    }
}
```

And just change `previewingContext.sourceRect = self.view.convertRect(cell.frame, fromView: self.scholarsCollectionView)` to `previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.bounds`

P.S. Of course don't forget to remove `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate` on your view :)

Comment: Could you please explain what previwingControllers is?

Comment: @Viper hi! It is object of class returned by `registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(: sourceView:)`, because unregister method (`unregisterForPreviewingWithContext(:)`) take it as parameter, so you should store them somewhere.