# ios - Peek and Pop - keep corner radius of UIImageView inside UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, 3dtouch, peek-pop

My view is structured like this:

```
UITableView
|    
+-- MyTableViewCell
|  |  
|  +-- UICollectionView
|     |  
|     +-- MyCollectionViewCell
|       |  
|       +-- UIImageView
```

The UIImageView is named 'icon' and its layer has certain corner radius. 
I've implemented Peek and Pop for items inside the Collection View and it works, but I can't figure out how to include corner radius of the image in the preview frame.

This is how I register the tableView for previewing:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *), traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
}
```

And this is my previewing function (inspired from [here](https://www.natashatherobot.com/peek-pop-view-inside-tableviewcell/)):

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? MyTableViewCell else { return nil }

    guard let collectionIndex = cell.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: self.view.convert(location, to: cell.collectionView)) else { return nil }

    guard let collectionViewCell = cell.collectionView.cellForItem(at: collectionIndex) as? MyCollectionViewCell else { return nil }
    let iconRect = tableView.convert(collectionViewCell.icon.frame, from: collectionViewCell.icon.superview!)
    previewingContext.sourceRect = iconRect

    return someViewController

}
```

This is what I get in the preview frame when force touching the image, right before the new view controller is committed (so the outside is blurred):

[image: image1]

This is what I would like to achieve, corner radius of the image is preserved (screenshot from the App Store):

[image: image2]

By reading [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37494251/peek-pop-preview-ignores-cell-corner-radius-in-collection-view) I believe the issue is that I register the whole tableView for previewing, instead of its cells. However I could not find a solution that worked for Collection View cells inside Table View cells.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you override the UIImageView and create some sort of custom drawing functionality?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: Maybe something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705879/ios-create-a-uiimage-or-uiimageview-with-rounded-corners).  It's not what I said but you can definitely get access to the objects and customize them.

Comment: The image has corner radius set already and works fine. The issue is with Peek and Pop in the preview frame, I can't figure out how to keep corner radius when passing the icon rect to `previewingContext.sourceRect`

Comment: Ah yes you did say that.  My apologies. How about setting the background of UIImageView and/or parent views to transparent in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the frame, did you try using its cellAttributes? If there is a cornerRadius on the contentView.layer of the cell, this will keep that in mind. So something like this works for us:

```
let cellAttributes = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)

previewingContext.sourceRect = cellAttributes.frame
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The cornerRadius is actually set only on my imageView's layer, and not on the contentView's layer, so I don't think this could work.